# Notification still appear when app is closed

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-ondestroy

i'm trying to close notification when my app being closed,because when i close the app from (Recent Task / Swipe to exit),notification still appear and in case user try to click on notification the app will crash.

```
 @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        notification.cancel(1);
        try {
            MApplication.sBus.unregister(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

in `onDestroy()` but doesn't work because `onDestroy()` is not called everytime.

Comment: have you tried 
notificationManager.cancelAll(); instead of cancel this will cancel all the notifications from current application context.

Comment: @vikaskumar thanks for your comment but doesn't work as i say onDestroy is not called everytime ,so i can cancle my notification

Comment: from where you are calling activity/fragment

Comment: actually all my necessary code in MainActivity

Comment: yeah, onDestroy is not sure to be called but I guess it will fulfil requirement most of the time.

Comment: How about `onStop()` ?  It's [guaranteed to be called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395169/is-activity-onstop-guaranteed-to-be-called-api-11) for every Android version from API level 11+

Comment: Am I the only one thinking that the onDestroy() should be called just before the ending brace as it makes the other code unreachable? Anyone? see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22091136/should-we-call-the-super-class-before-or-after-we-execute-some-code?lq=1).

Answer (score 7):

problem solved

Add a java class file. Here file name is **KillNotificationService.java**

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
public class KillNotificationService extends Service{

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
//Toast.makeText(this, “service called: “, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
nMgr.cancelAll();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
return null;
}
}
```

Call this service in your **MainActivity** `oncreate` method.

```
startService(new Intent(this, KillNotificationService.class));
```

Add service in **Manifest** file

```
<service android:name=".KillNotificationService"/>
```

Comment: @crgarridos try to cancel your notification by using notification id 
`nMgr.cancel(your_notification_id);`

Comment: oups ! sorry I wanted to mean: calling from an activity

Comment: I originally voted up his answer after using the solution in my app I have discovered a problem with
`startService(new Intent(this, KillNotificationService.class));`.
After the app is closed `KillNotificationService.class` should also be killed.
This means you will get an `java.lang.IllegalStateException` the next time you start the app.