# Wakelock "DoNotSleep" Continue to crash..

Tags: android

From my last question : [My app crashes just because wakelock "DoNotSleep"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665791/my-app-crashes-just-because-wakelock-donotsleep)

I added the line : wakeLock.acquire();

But my problem continue... :

Thats my logcat :

```
05-15 12:46:29.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2066): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

05-15 12:46:29.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2066): java.lang.RuntimeException: WakeLock under-locked DoNotSleep

05-15 12:46:29.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):     at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.release(PowerManager.java:945)

05-15 12:46:29.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):     at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.release(PowerManager.java:916)

05-15 12:46:29.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):     at com.example.iw84u.GpsTracker.UpdateWithNewLocation(GpsTracker.java:190)

05-15 12:46:29.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):     at com.example.iw84u.GpsTracker.access$0(GpsTracker.java:169)

05-15 12:46:29.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):     at com.example.iw84u.GpsTracker$MyLocationList.onLocationChanged(GpsTracker.java:213)

05-15 12:46:29.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:261)

05-15 12:46:29.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:189)

05-15 12:46:29.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:206)

05-15 12:46:29.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

05-15 12:46:29.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

05-15 12:46:29.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)

05-15 12:46:29.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

05-15 12:46:29.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

05-15 12:46:29.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)

05-15 12:46:29.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)

05-15 12:46:29.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And in my code:

```
public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "DoNotSleep");
        wakeLock.acquire();
}
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();



    }
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // Here there's some calculations with the intent

        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;

    }
private void UpdateWithNewLocation(final Location loc) {
 wakeLock.release();
//Some commands and then .....
 stopSelf(); 
}
```

Note: I changed the wakeLock.release(); And put that at the start of the function UpdateWithNewLocation(final Location loc) Because otherwise it doesnt stop.

Now my problem is that I still get error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception occurs if a lock is released more times than it was acquired ([source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/os/PowerManager.java#PowerManager.WakeLock.release%28%29)):

```
    public void release()
    {
        synchronized (mToken) {
            if (!mRefCounted || --mCount == 0) {
                try {
                    mService.releaseWakeLock(mToken);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                }
                mHeld = false;
            }
            if (mCount < 0) {
                throw new RuntimeException("WakeLock under-locked " + mTag);
            }
        }
    }
```

You acquire the lock only once (in `onCreate`) but release it multiple times (in `UpdateWithNewLocation`)

So, instead of locking it in `onCreate()` and releasing it in `UpdateWithNewLocation()`, you should probably acquire it in the beginning of `UpdateWithNewLocation()` and release it in its end.

Comment: Ok i disabled wakelock and its working ... no errors But the service never get destroyed... And i cant even force close it :/